# antenna build wraped with wires

Tags: antenna

I bought an SDR stick like the following:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/TERRATEC-USB-DVBT-DVB-T-Stick-SDR-Radio-FM-RTL2832U-R820T-USB-DVB-T-DAB-FM-/253116591451?hash=item3aeeecad5b:g:PUgAAOSwTuJYqUeQ

I wanted to shorten the antenna wire so cut the wire that connects the SDR component to the antenna, the problem is, when I wanted to solder the two ends of the wire I saw that the wire is inside some kind of transperent tube (see picture) , and outside the tube there is lots of metal/copper wires/fibers... and I want to remove them and only leave the transperent tube and the wire in it as is.

[image]

Can I do that? will it effect something in the antenna? I'm just trying to do those changes because I build something compact... 
couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: That is a coaxial cable, a standard method to connect to antennas, or to move delicate signals between pieces of hardware, or to move powerful RF signals safely between pieces of hardware.

Comment: This type of wire is designed to be crimped.  You _can_ solder it, however, be really careful as the inner (clear) insulator (aka dielectric), tends to melt very easily.  Soldering these wires without a **heatsink** often results in shorts between the inner conductor and the shield.  I'll leave the question if you _should_ do it to the RF folks...

Comment: Idealy you shouldn't. But you can, given the frequencies aren't too high, and you don't care about some losses.

Comment: You must connect both the center conductor and the shield (the outer copper wires) (but not to each other!)  Ideally, you should put a new connector on the shortened cable, rather than splicing the cut cable.